# Reactive .NET (RX) nesting catches by returning the same Observable

Tags: c#, exception, system.reactive

I would like to introduce some specific error catching routine and then just retry subscribing to the same observable. Does this have any drawbacks:

```
 public static IObservable<int> GetObservable()
{
  return Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.Zero)
    .Select(x =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"Throwing");
      throw new Exception("ups");

      return Observable.Return(1);
    }).SelectMany(x => x)
    .Catch<int, Exception>(ex =>
    {
      return GetObservable().SubscribeOn(Scheduler.Default);
    });
}
```

Does the Catch actually hold some stuff and should not be used in this way? What are the implications? Should the `Catch` be treated as a "use once" routine and just get a Exception check on the `Do` and then at the bottom use `Retry`?